# Разбиение html страницы на отдельные файлы

Tags: html, gulp

Как разбить блоки в HTML на отдельные файлы, а потом просто импортировать, например в `index.html`?

Нужен ваш совет, возможно, на Gulp или ваш любимый способ.

Comment: через php инклудить, или pug юзать, или через rigger

Comment: Если правильно понял условия. Пишу статьи в разметке Markdown, потом компилирую их в HTML. Если нужно вставить один HTML-файл в другой, пользуюсь расширением [**pymdown_snippets**](http://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/snippets/). Создаю файл — `сниппет` — который нужно включить в другой файл, → [**вставляю относительную ссылку на сниппет**](http://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/snippets/#snippets-notation) в другой файл → после сборки сайта сниппет включается в файлы. Можно включать любое количество сниппетов в любое количество HTML-файлов. Спасибо.

Comment: Просто `frame`.. :D

Answer (score 1):

Мой любимый способ - это gulp + rigger:

gulpfile.js :

```
var rigger = require('gulp-rigger');

gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src(path.watch.html)
    .pipe(rigger())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html));
});
```

index.html :

```
//= templates/head.html
<div class="app">
    //= templates/header.html
    //= templates/content/content.html
    //= templates/footer.html
</div>
//= templates/footer_scripts.html
```

рядом с index.html лежит папка templates с указанным содержимом.

Answer (score 0):

Я лично использовал вот этот javascript(вставлю его снизу), вставляешь его в свой js файл, и потом уже просто в html файле вот этот тэг и путь к своему файлу `<div w3-include-html="./parts/nav.html"></div>`

Сам JS :

```
function includeHTML() {
    var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
    /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
    z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        elmnt = z[i];
        /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
        file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
        if (file) {
            /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4) {
                    if (this.status == 200) {
                        elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                    if (this.status == 404) {
                        elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";
                    }
                    /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
                    elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
                    includeHTML();
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
            xhttp.send();
            /*exit the function:*/
            return;
        }
    }
}
includeHTML();
```